# Java humble-video screen recorder issues

Tags: java, java-native-interface, video-capture, screen-capture, demo

Hello I am attempting to record video of my screen using the humble-video library.
I am running through the demo application [RecordAndEncodeVideo.java](https://github.com/artclarke/humble-video/blob/master/humble-video-demos/src/main/java/io/humble/video/demos/RecordAndEncodeVideo.java)
I have imported the required jars through maven and then called the main function with arguments:

```
video.mp4 --duration 5 --snaps 20
```

It hangs for ~10sec on line 83

```
final Rational framerate = Rational.make(1, snapsPerSecond);
```

It appears to be doing some sort of JNI work here but I have no idea what, the source isn't the most easy to understand. It does spit out a warning before the hang but I have no idea if this is relevant:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

I tried importing the `org.slf4j.impl` libraries but it then complains that it can't find the class `org.apache.logging.log4j.util.StackLocatorUtil`, I have the latest log4j libraries on the classpath but that particular class is not included..

Is this an old class which has since been removed from log4j? Is this warning message even relevant? Why does this line of code take so long to execute?! 
Thanks.

Comment: I should add, it does create the video eventually - but the hang occurs before the actual screen recording begins.

Comment: With a bit more research I found this thread https://github.com/artclarke/humble-video/issues/55 perhaps because I have 32bit and 64bit JVMs installed?